# Add a member in a struct that implements a trait specified

Tags: rust, struct, traits

Let's say I have this struct in Rust:

```rust
// Trait that allows objects that
// implement it to return themselves
// to the caller.
trait ReturnsSelf {
    fn get_self(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

struct Data {
    member: u32
}
```

How would I go to say that `member` doesn't have to be a `u32`, but should simply implement `ReturnsSelf` as a trait? And can I also say that member should either implement `ReturnsSelf` or be a `u32`? Or even both?

Comment: It's not *quite* clear what you want. Do you want something that implements `ReturnSelf`, or a `u32`? When you say "or even both", do you realize it literally means only `u32`, since (if `u32: ReturnsSelf`) only `u32` has the property of being both `u32` and implementing `ReturnsSelf`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a generic with a trait bound:

```rust
struct Data<T: RetursSelf> {
    member: T,
}
```